# Protected CSS on website?

Tags: css

I've been trying to view the file **master.css** over at http://www.campaignmonitor.com/ but for some reason I can't. Is it protected? I even tried using Firebug but even that refuses to display it. Is there some kind of protection for CSS in here we don't know about?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be protected, it looks empty...

Comment: It's magically protected by being an empty file.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to protect your css from Firebug since it renders the DOM as it is in it's memory. This is also what allows it and other developer tools to show changes in the DOM made by javascript etc. You can minify you css to make it hard for others to read it, but firebug will format it anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not protected, the file is simply empty. If you inspect the response header, you will find this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2011 19:32:34 GMT
ETag: "2bf639-0-495dab735ad00"
Last-Modified: Thu, 25 Nov 2010 06:28:36 GMT
Server: ECS (lhr/D38A)
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 0
```

Note the last line. The [`Content-Length` *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-Length#Content-Length) is `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Since Firebug can't find any rules from that stylesheet being applied onto anything, I suspect that stylesheet is in fact totally empty. Bear in mind that that's not the only file being linked to for styles; there are others.

Answer (score 1):

The css file is just empty.

You can't protect a css file.  If so; how would your browser know how to render it?

Answer (score 1):

The master.css file is indeed empty.

The Chrome Webkit Inspector gives me theses urls for the css used:

- http://i2.campaignmonitor.com/min/?g=screen&1303274490
- http://i2.campaignmonitor.com/min/?g=home&1285746846
- http://i2.campaignmonitor.com/min/?g=print&1219642618
- http://i3.campaignmonitor.com/themes/site_themes/default/css/master.css

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its an empty file.

The only way I know to protect is to deliver a CSS by PHP and check for referrer. Empty or wrong referrer leads to an empty file on the client-side. So if you try to load the styles not in context of the website, you would see nothing. You can also check for browser type and deliver the appropriate styles.

Comment: Good idea, though not perfect: As long as the browser gets the css file, the user almost always has a way to read it. Something like this plus obsfucating would be a "good" (though highly useless) practice.

Comment: @JoshLeaves you are right, for CSS it might be useless, but for JavaScript it is an easy way of protection against bots.

If you render a HTML form by JavaScript and the PHP script that renders the JavaScript is awaiting some special referrer. It is doing a good job when combined with a mechanism working with hidden form fields.

I have different websites with this running for the contact forms and had never problems with bots. Since years and always without strange captchas.

Comment: Even like this, javascript content can still be accessed by a human reader, just as it is accessed by the browser. Full protection in impossible but it's good to think of security.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is any kind of protection. It looks like a mistake to me. The master.css file looks blank for some reason. The styling is coming from the other CSS files (http://i2.campaignmonitor.com/min/?g=screen&1303274490, http://i2.campaignmonitor.com/min/?g=home&1285746846, http://i2.campaignmonitor.com/min/?g=print&1219642618).

Answer (score 0):

It's just an empty file... Theres nothing to see...

Check this out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has the best protection there is
The file is empty. :-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @flem If you look at the accepted answer, you'll see it contains the same *answer* as mine, namely that the file the TS is talking about is an empty file. Please don't comment without reading carefully, as it makes you look stupid. Also check the date! It also had more more appropriate to just flag the post instead of posting a comment.

Comment: That comment is a predefined one from the SO review tool. It was the best fit.